# adding Variable to my array

Tags: arrays, swift

```
struct Section {
    var name: String!
    var items: [String]!
    var collapsed: Bool!

    init(name: String, items: [String], collapsed: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
        self.collapsed = collapsed
    }
}
```

this is my struct and I have variable such below

```
var array1 : Section = Section(name:"",items:[])
```

how can I add new name to my `array1` ? I don't want to append that I need something like below

```
sections = [
            Section(name: "Mac", items: ["MacBook", "MacBook Air", "MacBook Pro", "iMac", "Mac Pro", "Mac mini", "Accessories", "OS X El Capitan"]),
            Section(name: "iPad", items: ["iPad Pro", "iPad Air 2", "iPad mini 4", "Accessories"]),
            Section(name: "iPhone", items: ["iPhone 6s", "iPhone 6", "iPhone SE", "Accessories"]),
        ]
```

Comment: `array1.name = "new name"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is for array1 to itself be an array of Sections:

```
var array1: [Section] = []

array1.append(Section(name: "Mac", items: ["MacBook", "MacBook Air", "MacBook Pro", "iMac", "Mac Pro", "Mac mini", "Accessories", "OS X El Capitan"]))

array1.append(Section(name: "iPad", items: ["iPad Pro", "iPad Air 2", "iPad mini 4", "Accessories"]))

array1.append(Section(name: "iPhone", items: ["iPhone 6s", "iPhone 6", "iPhone SE", "Accessories"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly you can replace name this way:

```
var array1 : Section = Section(name:"",items:[])
array1.name = "New Name"
print(array1)  //Section(name: New Name, items: [], collapsed: false)
```

**EDIT:**

```
var array1 : Section = Section(name:"",items:[])

array1.name.append("New FamilyName")    //"New FamilyName"
array1.name                             //"New FamilyName"
```

As you can see `array1.name` was empty and you have append `"New FamilyName"`. In result it will give you `"New FamilyName"`

but if there is value in your `array1.name`

```
var array1 : Section = Section(name:"New Name",items:[])

array1.name.append("New FamilyName")    //"New NameNew FamilyName"
array1.name                             //"New NameNew FamilyName"
```

This will append new string into existing string.

Now if you completely replace without using append

```
var array1 : Section = Section(name:"New Name",items:[])

array1.name                           //"New Name"
array1.name = "Complete New Value"    //replace original value 
array1.name                           //"Complete New Value"  
print(array1)                         //"Section(name: Complete New Value, items: [], collapsed: false)\n"
```

Comment: if i use array1.name.append("New FamilyName") it will show me Section(name: New Name , New Family Name,items: [] , collapsed : false) but i want to show me Section (name New Name ...) . Section (name: New FamilyName)

Comment: That means you are appending characters into string.

Comment: Ok updating my answer.

Comment: but i dont want to replace that i want keep New Name and Create new one such as  Section (name: NewName ,items:[], colaps: false )
               Section (name: FamilyName ,items:[],collapse: true)

Comment: So you want to add new object in `array1 `?